# Why cant I process my ajax function if the form submits?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

this is my problem. I am trying to validate a form and make sure the username is available before allowing the form to submit. All my functions work properly, including my PHP script checking the username. However I cannot stop the form from submitting on submit.  What I get is an AJAX .error(message) that I have defined. Firebug reports

```
throw Components.Exception("prompt aborted by user", Cr.NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE);
```

However, when I invoke e.preventDefault(); outside of the username_exists function, it stops the form submitting, and will allow me to do my check inside of the afore mentioned function. I am totally stumped, and hope you can help. Thanks.

PS. I Cannot even do a simple alert() inside that function

```
$(function(){
    check_username_onsubmit();
});


function check_username_onsubmit(){
    $this = $('#username.registerForm');
    $('form.registerForm').submit(function(e){
        username_exists($this, function(data){
            if(data.found == 1){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('Username Taken');
            }else{
                alert('Username Free');
            }
        });
        // e.preventDefault();
    });
}


function username_exists($this, callback){
    var username = $this.val();

    $.ajax({
        url : '../includes/Single Scripts/username_exist.php',
        data : {
            username : username 
        },
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(data){
            callback(data);
        }
    }).error(function(){
            alert('An error has occured');
    });
}
```

Comment: You're making `$this` a global variable.  Maybe it's getting updated elsewhere?

Comment: @Rocket I have not used it anywhere else except inside functions.

Answer (score 2):

I would remove the `<input type="submit">` and add a `<button id="send">` after `</form>`.

Then, do something like:

```
$('#send').on('click', function () {
    var uname = $('#username.registerForm').val();
    username_exists(uname, function (data) {
        if (data.found == 1) {
            alert('Username Taken');
        } else {
            alert('Username Free');
            $('form.registerForm').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:** Also:

```
function username_exists(username, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../includes/Single%20Scripts/username_exist.php',
        data: {
            'username': username
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            callback(data);
        }
    }).error(function () {
        alert('An error has occured');
    });
}
```

Comment: that is not a bad solution, but it is a hack. I would like an answer why my AJAX is not working

Comment: What has been added that helps?

Comment: @yehuda See line 2 of my top code block. There is no need for the `$this` variable. I just simply pass the value of the user name directly

Comment: @MBJ great idea. This just saved me some serious time.

Answer (score 2):

Submit, by its very design leaves the page.
AJAX, by its very design does not leave the page.

If you want to use JavaScript to validate your form before sending it to the server, then get rid of the submit button. Fire off your client side validation script on click, and if it passes, then do your AJAX call.

```
$('#someForm').on('click','#myButton', {}, aValidationFunctionToCall);

aValidationFunctionToCall : function (event) {
    // validate stuff
    // show the user the error of their ways
    // or call your ajax
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `check_username_onsubmit()`, throw in a `return false;` it will stop the form from submitting.

If you already knew that, then start checking to make sure that you properly attached your javascript method to your submit event, or submit click event. the function is probably not even getting called.

Comment: That's what `e.preventDefault();` is supposed to do.

Comment: I know how to stop a form fromo submitting, but i cannot even do a simple alert() inside my inner function.

Comment: It is properly attached as I explained that I can block the submit in click, just the Ajax function is not working